# Jest is not failing when using "resolves"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jestjs

I wrote a function I try to test with jest:

```
asyncUpperCase(value: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(value.toUpperCase())
    }, 1000);
  })
}
```

It recives a string and turns it into a upperCase string (asynchronally).

I have to tests:

```
it('upperCase with promise and then', () => {
  return myAsync.asyncUpperCase('hello world').then(value => {
    expect(value).toBe('HELLO WORLD');
  })
})

it('upperCase with promise and resolve', () => {
  const promise = myAsync.asyncUpperCase('hello world');
  expect(promise).resolves.toBe('HELLO WORLD');
})
```

First test works correctly. But the second test does never fail. So if I change the expected string to `ABC` it still exits with success. Why and how do i use `resolves` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest provides 3 options to properly handle asynchronous tests [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises)

#### Returning a promise

```
it('upperCase with promise and resolve', () => {
  const promise = myAsync.asyncUpperCase('hello world');
  return expect(promise).resolves.toBe('HELLO WORLD');
})
```

#### Using async/await

Which is quite the same as an async function will return `Promise<void>`

```
it('upperCase with promise and resolve', async () => {
  const promise = myAsync.asyncUpperCase('hello world');
  expect(await promise).toBe('HELLO WORLD');
})
```

#### Using a callback

```
it('upperCase with promise and resolve', (done) => {
  const promise = myAsync.asyncUpperCase('hello world');
  promise
        .then(result => expect(promise).toBe('HELLO WORLD'))
        .then(done);
})
```

---

also you may take a look at [Advance Timers by Time](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks#advance-timers-by-time)

Answer (score 4):

A promise is asynchronous and needs time to be resolved, there's no way how `resolves` can fail synchronous test. Without being chained inside a test, it will result in unhandled rejection if test run is long enough.

It should be:

```
await expect(promise).resolves.toBe('HELLO WORLD');
```